# Destructuring values from array nested inside an object.

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Given the following object:

```
const object = {
    greeting: "hi",
    farewell:"bye",
    specialArray:[10,20,30,40,50]
}
```

I need to retrieve the 3 first elements of the array into 3 separate variables `a` , `b` , `c`

how?

Comment: `var [a,b,c] = object.specialArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign to an array with the variables for a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const object = {
        greeting: "hi",
        farewell: "bye",
        specialArray: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
    },
    [a, b, c] = object.specialArray;

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to variables like given in the example

```js
const object = {
    greeting: "hi",
    farewell:"bye",
    specialArray:[10,20,30,40,50]
} 

let [a, b, c] = object.specialArray;

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is the answer you expect but what you are asking seems quite simple :

```js
const object = {
    greeting: "hi",
    farewell:"bye",
    specialArray:[10,20,30,40,50]
} 
var [a, b, c] = object.specialArray;
    
console.log('a : ' + a +', b : ' + b + ', c : '+ c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const object = {
greeting: "hi",
farewell:"bye",
specialArray:[10,20,30,40,50]
};
let [a,b,c, ...rest] = object.specialArray; 
console.log(a); // 10
console.log(...rest); // 40 50
```